# Master Detail entry in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to create an invoice screen. where there are a master and detail combination. I am facing a problem in adding the items. I have dropdowns to select products and add them to the invoice and also edit those lines on the go. Can anyone help to set the UI. I took help from this https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/add-edit-delete-table-row-example-using-jqueryexample.html. but no luck. and it does not have dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

`jquery` is a client side library that only runs in the web broser. To work with `Asp.net MVC` you will need server side codes too which will process the data on the server.

Here is a tutorial that explains how to create master-detail CRUD (Create Remove Update Delete) pages with Asp.net mvc and jquery: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cUlo1sfBZ4

If you are still stuck then let us know what you have tried on the server side and what problem you are facing.